# Trying to change my immutable array in React Native

Tags: react-native, immutability

I have a function that runs every time your location changes and I'm trying to set a value in my array when a certain if statement is found true. All I seem to be doing is removing everything from my variable except the value that I am changing. Bad explanation so here is some code...

The data starts like this:

```
this.state = { selectedItem: [] }
```

And will change to something like this during normal app use:

```
selectedItem: [{address: 'Somewhere', latitude: -37.826835, longitude: 144.992030, found: false }]
```

Here is where I am trying to change the data (This will always run after some data is added):

```
const newSelectedItem = () => {
    let copyB = {...this.state.selectedItem};
    copyB.found = true;
    return copyB;
};
this.setState({selectedItem: newSelectedItem});
```

When I try to run:

```
{this.state.selectedItem.address}
```

I see the initial value which would be the address "Somewhere" but when my function runs based on location change it disappears. What have I actually done to my data in my above function?
Have I just made it `selectedItem: [{found:true}]` or something dumb like that?

Comment: why do you need an immutable array in the first place? Calling setState will update the UI regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the end I was mapping a function to the data and not the data itself. This was my eventual solution...

```
const newMyWaypoinys = this.state.myWaypoints.map(a => {
    let copyA = {...a};
    if (copyA.address === wp.address) {
        if (copyA.address === this.state.selectedItem.address) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                selectedItem: {         
                    ...prevState.selectedItem,    
                    found: true  
                }
            }))
        }
    copyA.found = true;
    }
    return copyA;
});
this.setState({
    myWaypoints: newMyWaypoinys,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing fine except for one single thing , in this function :

```
const newSelectedItem = () => {
    let copyB = {...this.state.selectedItem};
    copyB.found = true;
    return copyB;
};
this.setState({selectedItem: newSelectedItem});
```

here copyB is now an object , but yours selected Item was an array. So the problem is now selectedItem is now an object when you do setState with newSelctedItem.

SO `copyB.found = true;` wouldnt evaluate anything rather, try `copyB[0].found = true;` so there the value will be accessed and return true accordingly.

And when you try to access the state , replace `{this.state.selectedItem.address}`
with `{this.state.selectedItem[0].address}` ,

Hope i helps. feel free to ask any doubts.

You can play around with this pen [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0012)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is pretty weird since you still get the initial value. There are some problems in your code:

1. You want to store your variables in a array: It's fine, but the problem comes from the way you retrieve and set your value. Since `selectedItem`, your `{this.state.selectedItem.address}` because this is an object destructuring. To do that, you have to destruct your array first, e.g: `item = selectedItem[0]` or using `map`, etc... After that, you can try: `item.address`.

   Another problem is from your `newSelectedItem`. Since `let copyB = {...this.state.selectedItem};` will destruct your `selectedItem`, take all its properties and set to `newSelectedItem`, it will make your `selectedItem` become an object, not an array anymore.
2. If your `selectedItem` stores only 1 object, so don't use array. This `selectedItem` will become:

```
selectedItem: {
    address: 'Somewhere',
    latitude: -37.826835,
    longitude: 144.992030,
    found: false
}
```

It looks like a JSON object, hence you can do: `selectedItem.address`

In case you still don't get it, place a little debug or a `console.log("selectedItem", this.state.selectedItem)` to see what happend, and you will find out.